# Cadena de texto con sucesión

Tags: java

Realizo un programa en java que permita genrar esta sucesión con una cadena de la siguiente manera:

Input:

hola mundo

como estan

cadena con sucesión:

hOLA mUndO

cOmO eStAn

Trate de realizarlo trasformando el input String a un array tipo string con un split, para luego con un if, ir checando las posiciones pares, y trasformando dicha letra que se encuentre en dicha posición a minusculas, y con las posiciones impares, lo mismo, solo que conviertiendo a mayusculas...
El problema esta en que el array tambien guarda los espacios en blanco, lo cual causa un desfase en la sucesión, y no se lo puedo quitar, ya que debo mostrar el texto con el formato del inputtext, que puedo hacer para cumplir la sucesión, sin alterar los espacios y saltos de linea que este posee?

les dejo una captura para que se aprecesie mejor el problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualmente el programa devuelve:

hOlA MuNdO

cOmO EsTaN

mi codigo:

```
public String cambiar(String cadena1)
{
    cambiar= cadena1.split("");

    for(int i=0; i<cambiar.length; i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            cambiar[i]=cambiar[i].toLowerCase();
        }
        else
        {
            cambiar[i]=cambiar[i].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
     for(int i=0; i<cambiar.length; i++)
    {
        textocambiado+=cambiar[i];

    }

    return textocambiado;
}
```

NOTA: no se me permite usar arraylist

La cuestion es que estoy trabajando con archivos planos, leo y escribo sobre un archivo .txt mediante un textarea(como muestro en la primera captura) la cuestion es que cada que agrego una cadena, este se almacena automaticamente con un salto de linea. Ahora, el metodo con el que me ayudaste funciona bien si solo existe una linea de texto en el textarea, pensaba que si tomaba la cadena despues de imprimir en el primer textarea, me ahorraria problemas, pero no es asi, ya que obtengo el mismo resultado cuando obtengo la cadena del textarea, que de cuando tomo la cadena de la variable del metodo leer archivo:

aqui estan mis metodos de leer y escribir:

```
 public String leer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    FileReader fr= new FileReader(ruta);
    br= new BufferedReader(fr);

    while((texto= br.readLine())!= null)
            {
                cadena+= texto+"\n";

            }
    br.close();
    sinespacios = cadena.replaceFirst("\n", "");
    cadena= sinespacios;

    return cadena;

}

public void escribir() throws IOException
{
    FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(ruta, true);
    PrintWriter pr= new PrintWriter(fw);


    if(!"".equals(frase))
    {
       pr.print("\n"+frase+" ");
    }
    pr.close();

}
```

El metodo para realizar la sucesión es la que me aportaste

y de esta manera despliego:

```
  private void btnchangeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    txtachange.setText(l.cambiar(txtaadd.getText()));
}
```

esto me esta enloqueciendo, como puedo hacer que todas las lineas sigan el mismo patron?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera segunda linea tiene una sucesión diferente a la de la primera, que es la manera correcta

Answer (score 0):

Podrías detectar cuando el elemento en el array es un espacio y en este caso no realizar cambios, agrega también una variable `contador` para determinar cuando si cambiarias a mayuscula o minuscula el character, esta variable ùnicamente aumentara cuando el elemento en el array no sea un espacio.:

```
    cambiar= cadena1.split("");

    int contador =-1;

    for(int i=0; i<cambiar.length; i++)
    {

        if(cambiar[i].trim().isEmpty()){

        //encuentra espacio.    

            continue;
        }else{
         // No es espacio, es caracter.
            contador++;
        }

        if(contador%2==0)
        {
            cambiar[i]=cambiar[i].toLowerCase();
        }
        else
        {
            cambiar[i]=cambiar[i].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
     for(int i=0; i<cambiar.length; i++)
    {
        textocambiado+=cambiar[i];

    }
```

De esta forma al definir las cadenas de ejemplo

```
hola mundo
como estan
```

Tendrías como resultado:

```
hOLA mUndO
cOmO eStAn
```

---

Actualización: además reemplaza en tu método `leer()` el salto de linea por un token que indique una linea nueva en este caso "-" :

```
 sinespacios = cadena.replaceFirst("\n", "-");
```

y al final del método cambiar() antes de retornar el valor reemplaza este token por un salto de linea:

```
public String cambiar(String cadena1)
{
    ...
    ...
    textocambiado = textocambiado.replace("-","\n");

    return textocambiado;
}
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta bien, pero no considera los saltos de linea, el texto "hola mundo

como estan", lo tomo de otro textarea, como muestro en la captura, y el resultado cuando cambio debe de ser: "hOLA mUndO

cOmO eStAn"

Comment: actualmente el programa me devuelve: "hOlA mUnDo 
CoMo EsTaN "

Comment: Funciona bien solo para la primera linea

Comment: @AxwellDuarte puedes agregar el código de como capturas las lineas?

Comment: claro, los adicionare todo

Comment: @AxwellDuarte me parece que tienes un error en la salida hOLA mUndO cOmO eStAn, la "d" de mundo tendría que ser mayuscula , me parece que debe ser hOlA mUnDo CoMo EsTaN , es así?

Comment: No la salida tiene que ser la siguiente siguiente: "hOLA mUndO

cOmO eStAn", fijate que es una cadena debajo de otra, pero ambas tienen la misma sucesion, posicion par, minuscula, posicón inpar, mayuscula

Comment: Solo que con el metodo, solo funciona por primera vez, luego del salto de linea, el comportamineto cambia a: par Mayuscula, inpar minuscula, que es lo que no deseo

Comment: intento controlarlo, pero no puedo...

Comment: ¿que puedo hacer, o en que fallo?

Comment: El texto haora se muestra sin espacios y sin saltos de linea, pero sigue siendo erronea: "hOlAmUnDoCoMoEsTaN"

Comment: necesitamos un "token" que indique una nueva linea, revisa la actualización de mi respuesta y aplica los cambios, de esta forma obtendràs : "hOlA mUnDo
cOmO eStAn"

Comment: Funciona, pero el token que agrego se queda y se depliega en el primer textarea, cosa que no deseo, ademas de que hay el salto de linea no es muy estetico

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95552/discussion-between-elenasys-and-axwell-duarte).

Comment: El metodo que corregiste sigue estando mal, devuelve: "HoLa MuNdO 
cOmO eStAn"

Comment: revisa bien los cambios que sugiero, de hecho al inicio no tenias problema con "hOLA mUnDo", al final agregue una imagen de lo que se obtiene como resultado: "hOLA mUnDo cOmO eStAn"